# How do I make the charts c two type: normal and stacked?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, visualization, vega-lite, vega

I want to have two typecharts in one visual.
[Desired example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7rHx.png)
[Current example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOPzM.png), [Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQUOQDMaZNKGI04Ady0gImAE5sA1nDQhTSWRBxITcWZhABfJUgAeNCIYATNmQaWQB1GgD6NABGd08QAKRMFFRtJEEGOH9UAG1QJhM7WGsANUUQVWcrVABmAAZ6pQYIOAC0AA5GpUw2FMFYxvrPAqLZEvQAaQqquBqY7pAWtrQAFkXe-rQxRpGQQuKYawARGerBpqXW9tQAJg2+jLQG4YBdBNt7VTYTBDR85QZKAMQTJGogXIAAiSmAYCEoywCCmhyThlFmcGRMLRmwyrwqSByNiQTEEVj2UCBILB1lyAHJEXTkXSMUzIXTcYI6fivET4EgAsJZOSFKBVKDsC5-sTSVYlPzBaErO9RYDBMCJeDsfCFUK4JCANR01B0g0o2HwlKyw3syEAClNZgYsgCdu1lCtZMhACoFvUCOacY9BABKI0AUhDdIJRN6bEEmBoOA8ryUxBU42S-zFSCgcDcaWU8bh8kL6jgghu+zGJR6dDJ1gAQjWjj0AJ44cE-AKhJ5KGQmAugNjJ9AQOEzXSV6yeuUgbtwEzWALZPMu0KaBIKxeGH66VzWJh9Xp-eIJBxwKCGPSRaKoP1KFwqHuyTSFtuGJBkMjOCiYcHjn8SjltO6CzgSvg5KAP6RGgqgZK08RKN4hggVWupKhBfhoLIIKCP2PxDvOo5GBOwFTlW4FKAuS7oCu0AuC+m4fGw8aJqOYoUTOrEJkmFSYB24KyMEvYDAkKiCD8qFcegGHCvxgnWMJCCiRU0AZDUoBjGQNS5CAADE6wAJxMAAbKZFT6R0ADsNk2ZZMRMGIUBGcqZ5KKCbY7nkoDICY5iGAJnaHk4FQqCYwomAASgKNAtAAKiOAAycCqAWtRKOFkUxT2CUjlFGhYM88TvO47xAA)

Comment: I have answered your question but kindly update your question as anyone who will be referring this example in future will not know what question you have asked exactly. So please provide some details of what you have done and what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 layers having bar chart instead of column. First layer will be a stacked layer in which filter is applied for `used` and `free` fields. Second layer can have the `total` field. Using `xOffset` you can position both the bar charts. Refer the code below or [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQUOQDMaZNKGI04Ady0gImAE5sA1nDQhTSWRBxITcWZhABfJUgAeNCIYATNmQaWQB1GgD6NABGd08QPUjo1ABmAAZ0pQCkTBRUbSRBBjh-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-aQdYBqqnBCFIShsj7OeNJ7qA0xkG05QgAAxNsACcTAAGwsU0dF9AA7Nx3EcTETBiFAjFqvECSQvmX7AqAvwQP8gLSc0NBJlJeZPvWeFik0chwAA8qocoPNcywgN87jpiAyAmOYhjwYhw5OE0SRROcqAxGIvb6ao3RXvwqw9qAVk2XmdnQkwjlKM5KTuZ5qjeXAV59AkmZsABuagIWak4S+bxNn4k4mO2qCnnACTGEgR7LrOpXxN8QA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}, "axis": {"domainWidth": 1}},
  "width": 300,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"branch": "V", "free": 300, "used": 800, "total": 1000},
      {"branch": "K", "free": 100, "used": 400, "total": 500},
      {"branch": "D", "free": 100, "used": 200, "total": 300}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "[ datum.used, datum.free, datum.total]", "as": "table"},
    {"calculate": "['used', 'free', 'total']", "as": "headline"},
    {"flatten": ["table", "headline"]},
    {
      "calculate": "datum.headline +':'+ datum.table + ' ('+round(datum.table *100/ datum.total)+'%)'",
      "as": "tooltip"
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "table", "axis": {"grid": false}},
    "x": {
      "field": "branch",
      "axis": {"grid": false, "domain": false, "labelAngle": 0, "ticks": false},
      "sort": {"op": "sum", "field": "table", "order": "descending"}
    },
    "tooltip": {"field": "tooltip", "type": "nominal"},
    "color": {
      "field": "headline",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {"range": ["#409b66", "#878787", "#1b5c9e"]}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"field": "headline", "oneOf": ["used", "free"]}}
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": 15, "xOffset": -10}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": 15, "xOffset": 8},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "total", "axis": {"grid": false}, "stack": false}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```